# OrderClosePrice returns a price different from the history pool

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mt4

When closing a (selected) existing order with the api, and in that moment I try to get the closing price, sometimes (Perhaps one out of ten times) returns a price diferent from the one I can see in the history pool.

The code is something like this:

```
RefreshRates();

if(type == OP_BUY)
{
    currentPrice = NormalizeDouble(MarketInfo(symbol, MODE_ASK), vdigits);
}
else if(type == OP_SELL)
{
    currentPrice = NormalizeDouble(MarketInfo(symbol, MODE_BID), vdigits);
}

if (meetsRequirementsToClose(currentPrice))
{
    desiredPrice = currentPrice;


    // And then....

    bool retVal = OrderClose(OrderTicket(), numLots, desiredPrice, currSlippage);
    if (retVal)
    {
        this.reportClosePrice (myOrderId, OrderClosePrice(), desiredPrice, numLots, "closing");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The order was previously selected using SELECT_BY_POS in the pool MODE_TRADES.

anyone knows how to fix it?

**Edited**:

We have a broker that sometimes respects the requested price... sometimes not.

Disregarding the fact that we have to change broker for a more reliable one, we cannot rely on the requested price.

The deviation we see is greater than one hundred points, both for better and for worse prices than the real ones.

Comment: Could a small slippage be the cause?
Also for the `desiredPrice` are you using the `OrderClosePrice()` which returns the current price at which the position can be closed?

Comment: @TheLastStark No, we are not using OrderClosePrice() for desiredPrice, but anyway, thats not the problem: `NormalizeDouble(MarketInfo(symbol, MODE_ASK), vdigits);` is used to check if we have the desired price (with OP_SELL, and when other requirements are meet).  The problem is that even with the exact price, it returns a different one (sometimes).

Comment: Just so you know `OrderClosePrice()` will return the correct price at which a selected position can be closed at the moment, so for an `OP_SELL` order(position) it would return the correct `Ask` price.
But to get to your original issue, I am assuming it is a slippage issue.
If not other possible issues are in the `meetsRequirementsToClose(currentPrice)` function or using wrong digits(I am assuming `vdigits` is not the same as `Digit or _Digit`)

Comment: Also, can you try selecting the order by its ticket, just before closing?
I have not confirmed this, but once the trade is closed, the index of the order has to be changed(because the pools have changed from `MODE_TRADE` to `MODE_HISTORY`)

Comment: @TheLastStark It looks than reselecting the order works: i'll confirm when the number of orders are statistically relevant

Comment: You shouldn't be closing Buy orders using Ask price or Sell orders using Bid price - that's doing it backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sugested by @TheLastStark, the problem is solved selecting the order by its ticket just before closing.

The final code is something like:

```
RefreshRates();
if(type == OP_BUY)
{
    currentPrice = NormalizeDouble(MarketInfo(symbol, MODE_ASK), vdigits);
}
else if(type == OP_SELL)
{
    currentPrice = NormalizeDouble(MarketInfo(symbol, MODE_BID), vdigits);
}

if (meetsRequirementsToClose(currentPrice))
{
    desiredPrice = currentPrice;


    // And then....
    int tickNum = OrderTicket();
    bool retVal = OrderClose(OrderTicket(), numLots, desiredPrice, currSlippage);
    if (retVal)
    {
        if (OrderSelect(tickNum,SELECT_BY_TICKET,MODE_HISTORY)== false)
        {
            //this.logger.error ("Error selecting the order");
             this.reportClosePrice (myOrderId, -1, desiredPrice, numLots, "closing");
        }
        else
        {
            this.reportClosePrice (myOrderId, OrderClosePrice(), desiredPrice, numLots, "closing");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```